# BigQuery wildcard date range with subselect seems to return null

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a quarterly report where some of the dates are generated from a lookup query. The input is `start_date = 20181001` and `end date = 20191231`. While I could just query the whole range, I don't need `Q1/2/3` so I'm dynamically generating the `in-between` dates.

The problem comes when I use them in the subquery with the `table_suffix`.

The dynamically generated ones don't work; it looks like it returns null and queries the entire table rather than date partitioned. But when I just hard code the values in a subquery, they work fine.

If I you query both date lookup tables, they look identical
[Results of both dynamically_created and hard_coded table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKW7S.png). So I have no idea where this error is coming from.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION  start_end() AS ( [parse_date('%Y%m%d','{start_date}'), parse_date('%Y%m%d','{end_date}')] );
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION wildcard_format(date_object date) as (replace(cast(date_object as string),"-",""));

-- create a calendar table 1 column "day" and one row for each day in the desired timeframe
WITH
  calendar AS (
  SELECT
    extract(quarter from day) quarter
    ,extract(year from day) year
    ,day
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( start_end()[OFFSET(0)], start_end()[OFFSET(1)], INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) AS day 
),

dynamically_created as (
select 
    wildcard_format(min(day))  start_py
    ,wildcard_format(max(case when year = extract (year from parse_date('%Y%m%d','{start_date}')) then day else null end))  end_py
    ,wildcard_format(min(case when year = extract (year from parse_date('%Y%m%d','{end_date}')) then day else null end))  start_cy
    ,wildcard_format(max(day)) end_cy
from 
   calendar 
where quarter = extract (quarter from parse_date('%Y%m%d','{end_date}'))
),

hard_coded as (
  SELECT 
    '20181001' as start_py
    ,'20181231' as end_py
    ,'20191001' as start_cy
    ,'20191231' as end_cy    
),

sesh_data as (
select 
    *
from 
`projectid.datasetid.summary_*` 
where  
    (SELECT _table_suffix between start_py AND end_py FROM dynamically_created) #not working
    (SELECT _table_suffix between start_py AND end_py FROM hard_coded) #working
),

select * from sesh_data
```

Comment: Just noticed that the image is wrong, it only shows the date range of october. irrelevant to the problem discussed though

Comment: Can you provide a little sample of your data?

Comment: not without a lengthy approval process unfortunately. i assume the problem manifests itself on any wildcard table. would I be right in saying you are having trouble replicating the problem?

Comment: Yes, I dont know exactly how your data is